# sql query properly executing in mysql but same query shows error in jsp compilation

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following query in mysql which works perfectly in mysql and is generating output table as well. But when i write it in jsp , it is showing an error.

```
String q2 = "select id,username,password,fname,email,dob,mobile,habits,attitudes,tastes,moral,economic,people,imagess"
        + "from user, request "
        + "where user.habits='" + q1 + "'"
        + " and user.username=request.rto"
        + " and request.rfrom='" + username + "'"
        + " and request.status='Accepted'";
```

the error being displayed is,

> An error occurred at line: 118 in the jsp file: /search1.jsp
>   String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
>   stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: First: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL and `PreparedStatement`. Next, I'd advise you to stick to just presentation code in your JSPs...

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` to avoid these errors.

Comment: Each row (sub-string in the query) should end with a double quote (`"`). Java does not support multiline strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra double quotes which is not balanced. Follow the suggestion provided by Jon Skeet and Luiggi Mendoza as it is best practices to avoid these kind of problem and will help you to avoid sql injection as well

```
  String q2 = "select id,username,password,fname,email,dob,mobile,habits,attitudes,tastes,moral,economic,people,imagess"
            + " from user, request "
            + "where user.habits='" + q1
            + "' and user.username=request.rto"
            + " and request.rfrom='" + username
            + "' and request.status='Accepted'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your query, while you have built your sql query, you have missed one space between end of the selected column names and from clause

A space is required before from (**imagessfrom**)

Below is the correct one

```
String q2 = "select id,username,password,fname,email,dob,mobile,habits,attitudes,tastes,moral,economic,people,imagess"
        + " from user, request "
        + "where user.habits='" + q1 + "'"
        + " and user.username=request.rto"
        + " and request.rfrom='" + username + "'"
        + " and request.status='Accepted'";
```